# JavaScript - Scan and create link files from a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a bunch of local HTML files and I'm trying to translate them thanks to xml files and a lot of JavaScript/JQuery. The translation part is done and I'm now trying to do a pulldown menu with all of the xml files to select the desired language.

First, I tried to scan a local folder named "images" and print the name of my files in a blank html page but I was not able to do it. I did a lot of research on stack overflow and on [forum.jquery.com](http://forum.jquery.com) but even if I tried a lot of things, nothing worked.

Here is what I pulled of for the moment :

HTML side :

```
<body>
    <div id="fileNames">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <script>window.onload=ChangeLangue</script>
</body>
```

JS/Jquery side :

```
var folder = "images/";
$.ajax({
    url: folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
                $("body").append("<img src='" + folder + val + "'>");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible?

Comment: When you say 'local' do you mean on the client machine? If so that's not possible. Browser security prevents access to the local file system - and for very good reason.

Comment: I meant on my own computer, not on a network.

Comment: Still the same. The browser does not allow JS to access the local file system. If it did I would already have access to all the files on your computer ;)

Comment: Damn :( Thanks for the fast answer !

Comment: You can use an input of type file but that requires user interaction, a click for instance

Comment: I'm trying to do so: it scan the folder automatically, search for xml files "en-us.xml" for exemple and then display the name of the file on the screen. And all of that without an human intervention

Comment: @Alex But that's of course not possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers don't allow cross origin requests. An error will be thrown as
`Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.` Because the protocol is `file://`

**You can do it by setting a flag:**

1. Quit Chrome.
2. Restart using following command.

**MAC** : In terminal, `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files`

**WINDOWS** : In Run, `C:/PATH_TO_CHROME_INSTALLATION_FOLDER/chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`

Now you can access the files from your computer. To verify it, you can go to `chrome://version` and you can see the `flag` enabled under the `Command Line` section.

As you have `var folder="images/"`, and suppose the page loaded in the browser is in `/Users/Default/Desktop` folder, the ajax request made will be

`file:///Users/Default/Desktop/images`

If you add `/` before the folder `var folder = "/images/"`,
the request will be `file:///images/`.

Make sure to provide the required/complete path.

After getting the response, since the response is in html format, you can use `document.write(response)`. From there you can view and navigate in/out of folders.

I tried with below JS Code and got the result.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var url = "/Users/Default/Downloads";
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET",url,true);
    req.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(req.readyState === 4)
        {
            document.write(req.responseText);
        }
    };
    req.send();
</script>
```

P.S. : No idea if it works in Windows machines. Correct me if I am wrong. TIA.

Comment: The problem you explained is exactly what's happening. I tried your solution but the command don't seems to work on windows. 
Thanks for your help, I will find another way to do this!

Comment: Quit all chrome instances, go to Run and execute the command -  **chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-file**. This works I think so. Not tested just Googled.

Comment: Yes that what i tried but i get the same error ("Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."). It seems that using firefox for windows don't bring up this error, because all of the HTML page i did work fine with firefox but not with Chrome (I was using firefox since the start). Your JS is a good start i will continue with it. Thanks for your help