# get filenames in a given directory using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file

(I found some similar questions but none of them solved my problem so this is not a duplicated question I think)

I want to retrieve filenames in one of my folder using jQuery. I tried the following method but I still can't get each filename.

```
$.get(".", function(data) {
    $("#divID").append(data);
});
```

But I noticed that the type of 'data' is string and it contains filenames at the end of it like this:

```
<script>addRow("filename.csv","filename.csv",0,238618,"233 kB",1512119177,"12/1/17, 5:06:17 PM");</script>
```

So is there anyway I can retrieve the filenames from 'data'? (not by using regex)

Comment: I believe that you are trying to retrieve only the first filename.csv from the data parameter and not actually trying to read folder structure on your local file system. jQuery will not be able to access your local file system. Please add more details to your question.

Comment: @CharanrajGolla I want to get all the filenames first and read those files then. I know how to get content of the file but not each of the filenames.

Comment: You can not read file from a remote server or local server using JavaScript on the client machine. You can use server side code to get the file details and send it across to the client via ajax but it will always be string containing details of the list. If you want content of the file then your JS will have to make a request to server to read the file and provide it's output which will again come as string.

Comment: @CharanrajGolla what's the best practice to read filenames with server side code?

Comment: You can write a server side code say "Files/GetFile/" which will get list of all files and pass it across as JSON string. This can be used to displaying list of all files. If you need to display content of the file then make a second ajax request with the unique file identifier to server and read the content and return the string. This string can then be displayed under appropriate element on the page at client side

Comment: Thanks all I think I'll just use regex to retrieve filenames from data. That's the easiest way IMO

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read files in a client's machine. You may access them for development purpose by modifying a flag. Look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48080689/javascript-scan-and-create-link-files-from-a-folder/48081514#48081514) here regarding this. After this proceed with the below code.

Both works.

Using **PURE JAVASCRIPT** :

```js
var filenames=[], foldernames=[];
var url = "file:///Users/Default/Downloads";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET",url,true);
req.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(req.readyState === 4)
    {
        document.write(req.responseText);
        getNames();
    }
};
req.send();

function getNames()
{
    var files = document.querySelectorAll("a.icon.file");
    var folders = document.querySelectorAll("a.icon.dir");
    files.forEach(function(item){filenames.push(item.textContent)})
    folders.forEach(function(item){foldernames.push(item.textContent.slice(0,-1))})
    console.log(filenames);
    console.log(foldernames);
}
```

Using **JQUERY** :

```js
var filenames=[], foldernames=[];

$.get("file:///Users/Default/Downloads",function(response){
    document.write(response);
    getNames();
});

function getNames()
{
    var files = document.querySelectorAll("a.icon.file");
    var folders = document.querySelectorAll("a.icon.dir");
    files.forEach(function(item){filenames.push(item.textContent)})
    folders.forEach(function(item){foldernames.push(item.textContent.slice(0,-1))})
    console.log(filenames);
    console.log(foldernames);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```